# SharePoint 2013 Hashtag searching not working

Tags: search, 2013, social-tag, hashtags

I've got SharePoint 2013 running and everything seems to be running fine. My Search Service App and Mysites are all up and working fine. I can search for people, content etc. The only thing that is not working is Hashtag searching. When I click on a Hashtag link, i get no results. Also in the Trending tags on mysite, I get a message:

```
"Tagging's been quiet lately. No trending tags right now."
```

Any idea?